Show $\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k!} <\frac{5n-2}{2n}$ by induction.
$$\text{I want to show that $\forall n \in \mathbb N$:  }\ \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k!} <\frac{5n-2}{2n}$$
$$\text{The base case is valid, since:   }\ \frac{5\cdot1-2}{2\cdot1}>1$$
$$\text{After assuming: }\ \sum_{k=1}^{n} \ \frac{1}{k!} <\frac{5n-2}{2n}, \ \text{ I am a bit lost.}$$
I have tried to rewrite the RHS as $\frac{5n-2}{2n}=\frac{5}{2}-\frac{1}{n}$, but this does not seem to help.
Any help or suggestions is appreciated.

Why downvotes? Is the question poorly stated?

I didn’t downvote, but they are probably due to a lack of context for the problem.

As $n$ increases, the RHS increases by
$$\frac52 - \frac1{n+1} - \left(\frac52 - \frac1n\right)$$
$$=\frac1n - \frac1{n+1}$$
$$=\frac1{n(n+1)}$$
$$\ge\frac1{(n+1)!}$$
so the inductive step is valid.
